# Assemble.io - Looping around a YAML List : {{each}} vs {{eachProperty}}

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

If I have a YAML list, e.g:

Home : /
  Terms and Conditions : /terms.html

And I want to render some content from that list, but make use of both keys & values, I'm having to use {{eachProperty}} to get those values, i.e :

{{#eachProperty this.value}}

{{key}}

{{/eachProperty}}

Anyone got any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to add another layer to your YAML data structure, so you have a list of pages, where each page is an object that has both a title and url property you can reference in the template.  In the example below, I put the YAML at the top of the Handlebars template, but it should work the same if loaded from an external file.

```
---
links:
  Home:
    url: '/'
    title: 'Home'
  Terms:
    url: '/terms.html'
    title: 'Terms and Conditions'
---
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Test List of Links</h1>
<ul>
    {{#each links}}
        <li><a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, my data structure is a bit too simplistic for maintain what is basically a list of urls;

It's not just simple to have a key name to acts as both a match for the url, as well as a displayed nav link, as hypens etc may come into play.

Wonder if anyone has published any patterns on what are good YAML data structures to hold such data...

Thanks though!